# Почему Angular постоянно открывает главную страницу

Tags: javascript, angular, framework, angular-routing

Каждый раз, когда я перехожу на `'/'`, мне выводится `static-root-component` (компонент главной страницы), но когда я перехожу на `'/welcome'`, меня мгновенно возвращает на `'/'` и открывается `static-root-component`вместо `welcome-component`

Вообше мне нужно перенаправлять пользователя на `'/welcome'`, если он не авторизован на сайте, однако получить статус авторизации можно только в .js файле (авторизация через OpenAPI ВКонтакте), после проверки скриптом статуса пользователя, решается будет ли он перенаправлен, и если да, то с помощью `location.replace("/welcome")`, однако... Сразу после Angular возвращается на `'/'`

> "весёлый", но важный факт: при дэбаге через `ng serve` все идёт как надо, но после компиляции `ng build` все ломается

Я не знаю, в чем может быть проблема, привожу `app.module.ts`:

````
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StaticRootComponent } from './static-root/static-root.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome/welcome.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpService } from './http.service';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

const appRoute: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: StaticRootComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    StaticRootComponent,
    WelcomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoute),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [HttpService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }```
````